# WHERE clause columns based on CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, case-statement

I am running into an issue with how to tackle a WHERE clause that will compare different columns based on the value of a variable.

In English, this is my goal:

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    [LaborDtl].[ClockInDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND
    /* (this is where I get lost) */
    CASE WHEN @SearchBy = R THEN [LaborDtl].[ResourceGroupID] IN (SELECT val FROM STRING_SPLIT(SELECT value FROM string_split(@SearchTerms, ','))
    ELSE [LaborDtl].[JCDepartment] IN (SELECT val FROM STRING_SPLIT(SELECT value FROM string_split(@SearchTerms, ','))
```

Basically, if @SearchBy = R, then show me the rows where the ResourceGroupID is in the @SearchTerms list, otherwise show me the rows where the JCDepartment value is in the @SearchTerms list.

I saw a post somewhere that said you can't use an 'IN' statement in a CASE if it is in a WHERE clause, so I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction of another way to tackle this issue.

Comment: @Gordon `STRING_SPLIT` is almost certainly SQL Server.  And the square brackets basically rule out everything except for SQL Server and Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` expressions are generally not needed in the `where` clause.  So just rewrite the logic to:

```
WHERE [LaborDtl].[ClockInDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
      ((@SearchBy = 'R' AND
        [LaborDtl].[ResourceGroupID] IN (SELECT val FROM STRING_SPLIT(SELECT value FROM string_split(@SearchTerms, ','))
       ) OR
       (@SearchBy <> 'R' AND
        [LaborDtl].[JCDepartment] IN (SELECT val FROM STRING_SPLIT(SELECT value FROM string_split(@SearchTerms, ','))  
       ) 
      )
```